# Repositories in sources.list (Debian)

Tags: terminal, debian, repository

I'm just interested to know how your sources.list look like. I got some repositories witch give some errors and I would like to clean it up.

and when I do apt-get update I get few lines showing errors like 404 , this is how my list look like:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.2.1 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20110628-13:01]/ squeeze main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.2.1 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20110628-13:01]/ squeeze main

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.ba.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.ba.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main

#non free and contrib

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://download.skype.com/linux/repos/debian stable non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates contrib non-free main
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates contrib non-free main

#wine
deb http://wine.sourceforge.net/apt/ binary/
```

Errors after apt-get update:

> Err [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url]
>   squeeze/updates/main Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80] Err
>   [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url]
>   squeeze/updates/contrib Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>   Err [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url]
>   squeeze/updates/non-free Sources   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>   Err [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url]
>   squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36
>   80] Err [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url]
>   squeeze/updates/contrib i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
>   128.30.2.36 80] Err [url=http://http.us.debian.org]Index of /[/url] squeeze/updates/non-free i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP:
>   128.30.2.36 80] Fetched 2,759 B in 26s (102 B/s) N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has
>   an invalid filename extension N: Ignoring file
>   'lenny.non-free.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as
>   it has an invalid filename extension N: Ignoring file
>   'opera.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an
>   invalid filename extension N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.save'
>   in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename
>   extension W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/main/source/Sources.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/contrib/source/Sources.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/non-free/source/Sources.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   [url]http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages.gz[/url]
>   404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.36 80]
>
> E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

So if you have some recommendations how to fix these errors ( or show me your repositores list) I would be very grateful ;) cheers;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort out the error by comment out all the repolist except as follow  in the sources.list.

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free 
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
```